# Not sure if question is appropriate here or graphics exchange, but is relevant to photography editing

Tags: discussion

## How do Photo editing apps that allow you to draw on pictures work?

- [Example of an image where a user has drawn on a picture[image: List item]](https://i.stack.imgur.com/u1k0E.png)

What happens in the background of an application?

What programming language(s) are primarily used for this?

Is there a reason why most photo editing applications are native applications versus websites? ( I am assuming they need more compute)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is not on topic here or on graphics design as it has to do with software design, not photography or graphics design.  The software design you are interested in happens to be making photo editing software, but what the software is doing is irrelevant to the design questions.  Stack Overflow is the correct place to ask this question or perhaps Super User depending on the level of detail you are looking for.

Comment: I'd second Super User.

Comment: @mattdm @ AJ Henderson Thank you both for getting back to me. I will ask this question in super user.